# How do I know if Ubuntu 22.04 has any virus?

Tags: dual-boot, malware, antivirus, visual-artifacts, troubleshooting

I have a Windows / Ubuntu 22.04 dual boot. I get screen artifacts as shown below.

[image]

At that moment, what I restarted Ubuntu. When it turned on, it no longer appeared and, until now all the applications and files that I have are working correctly. Is there any way to know if I have a virus? And if so, what should I do to remove it?

Comment: FYI:  Virus (*or malware that infects & then spreads to other systems to infect them*) is really a windows specific issue.  Yes there are other forms of malware (*trojans etc*) that impact both windows, gnu/linux (thus Ubuntu), bsd etc that will impact a Ubuntu system, but *virus* no.

Comment: "How do I know if Ubuntu 22.04 has any virus?"  askubuntu would be overrun by questions about that malware ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repetitive pattern of fuzzy screen artifacts was not caused by a virus. It looks like it was caused by a hardware issue with your laptop's graphics processor or possibly in its RAM. If the visual artifacts problem occurred just once and doesn't reoccur I wouldn't worry about it. If the problem gets worse you should take the laptop to a technician for a checkup.

Another symptom to watch for is if the screen freezes when playing a video, but the audio keeps on playing a short audio clip in a loop. That's usually caused by a hardware problem with GPU RAM too.

Comment: Thank you, your answer has been so kind. You were right, it was a hardware problem on my computer.